# How can i use argv in my code to do a result properly?

Tags: python, argv, sys

I try to use argument in a basic code to understand and fully exploit `sys.argv`
so i try to write a code and i do that :

```
import sys

aa = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]

print("hello {} and {}".format(aa, b))
```

In my terminal a wrote

```
python test.py Thomas Michael
```

But nothing happend and i still don't understand why lmao

(because when i write manually in my algorithm the two name for my example, it work)

Comment: strange, I tried it and found it working on my machine

Comment: Do you have any errors? or just no output?

Comment: it works for me too. Maybe you run different `test.py` which doesn't use `print()`.

Comment: I have no errors, just no output
And I isolate the file in a folder alone and retry but still not work, i think I'm going to execute the file in a vm to make it work   

Thanks everyone !
(If it doesn't work only for me, i just going to try in vm or an another pc)